# Not a Unique table/alias- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the error " Not a Unique table/alias 'Customer' " when I run my join statement. I want to display all the information that I have. I've researched the JOIN statements and I can't find what's wrong.

```
    SELECT Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName,     Customer.StreetAddress,Customer.City,Customer.State,Customer.Zipcode, Customer.HomePhone,Customer.MobilePhone,Customer.OtherPhone, Pizza.PizzaID,
Pizza.PizzaName, Pizza.Description, Pizza.UnitPrice, OrderInformation.OrderID, OrderInformation.OrderDate, OrderItem.Quantity  


 FROM Customer

 JOIN OrderInformation ON OrderInformation.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
 JOIN Pizza ON Pizza.PizzaID = OrderItem.PizzaID
 JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustomerID = OrderInformation.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
...
FROM Customer
...
JOIN Customer
```

You're selecting `FROM Customer` and then doing `JOIN Customer`, meaning you now have two instances of `Customer`. When you reference something like `Customer.CustomerID`, your query doesn't know which iteration of the `Customer` table you're referring to.

If you actually needed two references to the same table, you could give one an alias. However, being that you reference an `OrderItem` table, but never `JOIN` or select `FROM` it, I have a hunch that one of those `Customer` tables should be `OrderItem`. Perhaps like this...

```
SELECT ...

FROM OrderItem

JOIN OrderInformation ON OrderInformation.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
JOIN Pizza ON Pizza.PizzaID = OrderItem.PizzaID
JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustomerID = OrderInformation.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you use table aliases.  It would appear that the first reference to `Customer` should really be `OrderItem`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName,       
       c.StreetAddress, c.City, c.State, c.Zipcode, 
       c.HomePhone, c.MobilePhone, c.OtherPhone,
       p.PizzaID, p.PizzaName, p.Description, p.UnitPrice, 
       oinf.OrderID, oinf.OrderDate, oi.Quantity  
FROM OrderItem oi JOIN
     OrderInformation oinf
     ON oinf.OrderID = oi.OrderID JOIN
     Pizza p
     ON p.PizzaID = oi.PizzaID JOIN
     Customer c
     ON c.CustomerID = oi.CustomerID;
```